# How can I set cookie header using react and request-promise

Tags: reactjs, cookies, request-promise

"Cookie" header is never sent, even when browser console shows otherwise

I am trying to use request-promise and Reactjs to send request from my web application to SAP B1 Service Layer. First, I tried using the "headers" option in request-promise, then tried setting a cookie using rp.cookie("...") and jar.setCookie("...") but got errors both times.
The browser console is showing it is sending the "Cookie" header, but when I intercept the request using Burp Suite the header is never sent.

```
var rp = require('request-promise').defaults({jar:true});
var rd= require('request-debug');
rd(rp);

const b1jar=rp.jar();

let options = {
    method: method,
    rejectUnauthorized: false, 
    uri: url,
    insecure:true,
    jar:b1jar,
    json: true,
    resolveWithFullResponse:fullres,
// I TRIED TO USE THIS FIRST        
    headers: 
    { 'Cookie': "B1SESSION="+(sessionStorage.SessionID||'')+';',            
    }
};
//THEN DELETED THE headers OPTION AND TRIED WITH THE jar OPTION
var b1cookie=rp.cookie('B1SESSION='+sessionStorage.SessionID);
b1cookie.setExpires(moment().add(sessionStorage.SessionTimeout,'m')
.toDate());
b1jar.setCookie(b1cookie,config.server);
res = await rp(options);
```

The expected result is that the B1SESSION Cookie should be sent when using rp(options), but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

That API is pretty bad, try axios...

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-axios
```